# Create dataframe from list

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to create a dataframe from list.
The content of list are this:

```
 [Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=333970434, symbol='ESGV', exchange='BATS', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESGV', tradingClass='ESGV'), position=1142.0, avgCost=52.7765556),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=238760476, symbol='ESGD', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESGD', tradingClass='NMS'), position=954.0, avgCost=64.1715282),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=26653236, symbol='DVY', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='DVY', tradingClass='NMS'), position=292.0, avgCost=101.06176745),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=27638087, symbol='VO', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='VO', tradingClass='VO'), position=50.0, avgCost=170.48881),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=27684036, symbol='VDE', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='VDE', tradingClass='VDE'), position=99.0, avgCost=81.962902),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=225020107, symbol='TFI', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='TFI', tradingClass='TFI'), position=1109.0, avgCost=50.50644005),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=43645865, symbol='IBKR', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='IBKR', tradingClass='NMS'), position=2800.0, avgCost=39.4058383),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=26787475, symbol='TIP', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='TIP', tradingClass='TIP'), position=207.0, avgCost=115.00465265),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=46577293, symbol='BWX', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='BWX', tradingClass='BWX'), position=712.0, avgCost=28.57725195),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=15547816, symbol='LQD', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='LQD', tradingClass='LQD'), position=99.0, avgCost=124.4389121),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=313845618, symbol='ESML', exchange='BATS', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESML', tradingClass='ESML'), position=309.0, avgCost=27.38696345),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=31230302, symbol='VNQ', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='VNQ', tradingClass='VNQ'), position=137.0, avgCost=88.7322321),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=238760480, symbol='ESGE', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESGE', tradingClass='NMS'), position=1221.0, avgCost=33.994677),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=338719585, symbol='EAGG', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='EAGG', tradingClass='EAGG'), position=1280.0, avgCost=53.3022901),
```

To create the list, y use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

but it returns df like this:

[image: df image]

How should I do, to be able to visualize all the information in the df in a correct way, to later select only the columns that I need?

Correctly = each comma, a column.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Pandas read list correctly. It is that you need to split sub-list into columns. There are answers for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
cols=[el.split("=")[0] for el in df['contract'].iloc[0].split(",")]
for el in cols:
    df[el]=""
df[cols]=df['contract'].str.split(",")
df[cols]=[df[col].str.split("=").apply(lambda x: x[1]) for col in cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
t = [{k: v for k, v in {**x.contract._asdict(), **x._asdict()}.items() 
      if k != 'contract'} for x in L]

df = pd.DataFrame(t)
```

---

```
print (df.head())
        conId symbol exchange currency localSymbol tradingClass   account  \
0   333970434   ESGV     BATS      USD        ESGV         ESGV  DUC00074   
1   238760476   ESGD   NASDAQ      USD        ESGD          NMS  DUC00074   
2    26653236    DVY   NASDAQ      USD         DVY          NMS  DUC00074   
3    27638087     VO     ARCA      USD          VO           VO  DUC00074   
4    27684036    VDE     ARCA      USD         VDE          VDE  DUC00074   

    position     avgCost  
0     1142.0   52.776556  
1      954.0   64.171528  
2      292.0  101.061767  
3       50.0  170.488810  
4       99.0   81.962902
```

If ordering of columns is important use:

```
t = []
for x in L:
    out = {}
    d = x._asdict()
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, tuple):
            d1 = v._asdict()
            for k1, v1 in d1.items():
                out[k1] = v1
        else:
            out[k] = v
    t.append(out)


df = pd.DataFrame(t)
print (df.head())

    account      conId symbol exchange currency localSymbol tradingClass  \
0  DUC00074  333970434   ESGV     BATS      USD        ESGV         ESGV   
1  DUC00074  238760476   ESGD   NASDAQ      USD        ESGD          NMS   
2  DUC00074   26653236    DVY   NASDAQ      USD         DVY          NMS   
3  DUC00074   27638087     VO     ARCA      USD          VO           VO   
4  DUC00074   27684036    VDE     ARCA      USD         VDE          VDE   

   position     avgCost  
0    1142.0   52.776556  
1     954.0   64.171528  
2     292.0  101.061767  
3      50.0  170.488810  
4      99.0   81.962902
```

---

**Setup**:

```
L = [Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=333970434, symbol='ESGV', exchange='BATS', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESGV', tradingClass='ESGV'), position=1142.0, avgCost=52.7765556),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=238760476, symbol='ESGD', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESGD', tradingClass='NMS'), position=954.0, avgCost=64.1715282),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=26653236, symbol='DVY', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='DVY', tradingClass='NMS'), position=292.0, avgCost=101.06176745),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=27638087, symbol='VO', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='VO', tradingClass='VO'), position=50.0, avgCost=170.48881),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=27684036, symbol='VDE', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='VDE', tradingClass='VDE'), position=99.0, avgCost=81.962902),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=225020107, symbol='TFI', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='TFI', tradingClass='TFI'), position=1109.0, avgCost=50.50644005),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=43645865, symbol='IBKR', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='IBKR', tradingClass='NMS'), position=2800.0, avgCost=39.4058383),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=26787475, symbol='TIP', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='TIP', tradingClass='TIP'), position=207.0, avgCost=115.00465265),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=46577293, symbol='BWX', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='BWX', tradingClass='BWX'), position=712.0, avgCost=28.57725195),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=15547816, symbol='LQD', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='LQD', tradingClass='LQD'), position=99.0, avgCost=124.4389121),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=313845618, symbol='ESML', exchange='BATS', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESML', tradingClass='ESML'), position=309.0, avgCost=27.38696345),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=31230302, symbol='VNQ', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='VNQ', tradingClass='VNQ'), position=137.0, avgCost=88.7322321),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=238760480, symbol='ESGE', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESGE', tradingClass='NMS'), position=1221.0, avgCost=33.994677),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=338719585, symbol='EAGG', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='EAGG', tradingClass='EAGG'), position=1280.0, avgCost=53.3022901)]
```